# gcd finding method

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

An integer $d$ is a $\gcd$ of two non-zero integers $a$ and $b$, if

- $d$ divides $a$ & $d$ divides $b$
- '$c$ divides $a$ & $c$ divides $b$' implies '$c$ divides $d$' for any integer $c$.

If $e=gh$ where $e,g,h \in \{0,\pm1,\pm2,...\}, g\neq0$, then we say that $g$ divides $e$.

These are the definitions written in a maths book. 
The above definitions imply there are two gcd's, one a positive integer, another the negative of this positive integer. Am I correct?
How can I find the gcd's?
We find the hcf of │a│ and │b│ by division method, let it be $m \in \{1,2,\dots\}$. Then $m$ and $-m$ are the $\gcd$'s. Is this right?

Comment: Usually textbooks are more careful, and define the gcd to be positive.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Your book has decided not to distinguish one GCD as "the GCD."

Comment: As for finding the gcd, you can use the "Euclidean algorithm" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm